# avahi-daemon doesn't start (can't create runtime directory)

Tags: linux, avahi

I am trying to start `avahi-daemon` but it responds with and error

> `Failed to create runtime directory /opt/var/run/avahi-daemon/`

That directory do exist.

Even if I delete this folder and start `avahi` again it creates it but still keeps saying that its a fail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use proper formatting for your questions. Read [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Btw you're not telling us how you do proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that such cases be linked with a lack of privileges.

## => use `sudo`

e.g.

```
sudo service dbus start
sudo service avahi-daemon start
```

Another issue could be the missing space of the file system. To check that do:

```
df -h /opt/var/run/
```

Result musn't be 100%.